# Median over time - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, median, dense-rank

I have data (support ticket statistics, to be exact), that I am trying to get the median of, over time.

Right now, I have a query that calculates the difference between the date the ticket was opened and the date it was closed. I take that data and pivot the average of the days to close over a series of months and years, using SQL Servers built in AVG function. This works well, however I am finding that the metrics are skewed due to outliers in the data.

What I really want, is the Median of the data, pivoted over months and years. I am having trouble achieving what I am after, and I am not positive if this is even possible.

The query I have right now, using the AVG function, is:

```
SELECT 'Support - Days To Close Escalation', *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        DATEDIFF(HOUR, e.CreatedDate, e.Escalation_Close_Date_Time__c) AS DaysToCloseEscalation,                        
        LEFT(CONVERT(CHAR(10), e.CreatedDate,126), 7) AS EscalationCreateDate
    FROM [dbo].[Escalations] AS e WITH(NOLOCK)

    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Case] AS c WITH(NOLOCK)
    ON e.Case__c = c.Id

    WHERE e.Escalation_Queue__c IN ('PM 10 Tier 2 Support', 'PM 11 Tier 2 Support')
    AND e.CreatedDate BETWEEN '2017-04-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2018-04-01 00:00:00.000'
    AND e.Escalation_Close_Date_Time__c IS NOT NULL

) AS SupportEscalationVolume
PIVOT
(
    AVG(SupportEscalationVolume.DaysToCloseEscalation) FOR SupportEscalationVolume.EscalationCreateDate IN ([2017-04],[2017-05],[2017-06],[2017-07],[2017-08],[2017-09],[2017-10],[2017-11],[2017-12],[2018-01],[2018-02],[2018-03])
) AS SupportEscalationVolumePivot
```

The result of this query is something along the lines of (except all in a single row, since the data is pivoted):

```
StatDescription | Support - Days To Close Escalation
----------------------------------------------------
2017-04         | 107   
2017-05         | 52    
2017-06         | 101   
2017-07         | 106   
2017-08         | 69    
2017-09         | 54    
2017-10         | 49    
2017-11         | 42    
2017-12         | 51    
2018-01         | 31    
2018-02         | 23    
2018-03         | 15
```

After some research on how to pull of a Median in SQL, I have resorted to using DENSE_RANK(), as shown in the query below. I started with ROW_NUMBER(), but that gave me a counter for ALL records, where what I really want is a median of the time to close the ticket for each month/year grouping.

```
;
WITH SupportDaysToClose(HoursToCloseEscalation, EscalationCreateDate, RowNumber)
AS
(
    SELECT 
        DATEDIFF(HOUR, e.CreatedDate, e.Escalation_Close_Date_Time__c) AS HoursToCloseEscalation,                       
        LEFT(CONVERT(CHAR(10), e.CreatedDate,126), 7) AS EscalationCreateDate,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY LEFT(CONVERT(CHAR(10), e.CreatedDate,126), 7) ASC) AS RowNumber
    FROM [dbo].[Escalations] AS e WITH(NOLOCK)

    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Case] AS c WITH(NOLOCK)
    ON e.Case__c = c.Id

    WHERE e.Escalation_Queue__c IN ('PM 10 Tier 2 Support', 'PM 11 Tier 2 Support')
    AND e.CreatedDate BETWEEN '2017-04-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2018-04-01 00:00:00.000'
    AND e.Escalation_Close_Date_Time__c IS NOT NULL

)

SELECT *
FROM SupportDaysToClose
ORDER BY RowNumber,HoursToCloseEscalation
```

A sample of this data looks like

```
HoursToClose|CreateDate|RowNumber
---------------------------------
0           |2017-04   |1
7           |2017-08   |5
27          |2017-12   |9
```

Each RowNumber correlates to a given month and year, the maximum being at 12.

At this point, I am not really sure where to go.

Has anyone ever done anything like this before? I am not sure if I am on the right track or if I need to rethink the whole strategy. I apologize in advance if the syntax is difficult to follow.

Comment: have you seen this article: https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/median

Comment: Could you explain what exactly do you mean by `median over time` ? The [Median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) is just a "middle" element of ordered set, if the set contains an odd number of elements, or a sum od two "middle" elements divided by 2, if the set contain an even number of elements. How exactly do you want to calculate "medians over the time"? please explain

Comment: I was gonna say maybe use `PERCENTILE_DISC` or `PERCENTILE_CONT` if you have 2012+. You could then define the window over which you're interested, and the row in the 50th percentile. From there, if that's not enough, you could join that back to your table and get the values from the row that matches.

Comment: My apologies, I realized after I made the post that “median over time” could be confusing. Using SQL’s built in AVG function (mean) is easy, because all it does, in terms of my usage, is sum the “number of hours” and divide by the total, within a given month and year. I am having trouble figuring out how I should take a set of data for a given month/year, find the middle value, and pivot on it. I understand the concept of the median, and can do it with the entire set of data, but trying to take each months worth of data and get the median for each month is what I am struggling with.